# Allow dependent job to run manually GitlabCI

Tags: gitlab-ci

There are two tasks in gitlabci:

```
task1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
  when: manual

task2:
  stage: stage2
  needs: [ task1 ]
  script:
    - echo "world"
```

How can I make task2 available to run manually without running task1?
The condition of running task2 after successful execution of task1 shouldn't be broken.

Of course I can create another task, let's say

```
manual_task2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - echo "world"
  when: manual
```

but maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [needs: optional](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsoptional) keyword in task2 to make the dependent job optional.

```
task2:
  stage: stage2
  needs:
    - job: task1
      optional: true
  script:
    - echo "world"
```

This will allow you to run task2 without task1, but will also require task1 to successfully complete if it is triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I didn't know about this keyword.
But it seems that with your solution I'll have to set when: on_success. But this will not let me run this task manually.
I need to run the task2 automatically when task1 finishes and to have an opportunity to run task2 manually any time.